# How to upload a file in PHP using following code?

Tags: php

I would like to upload file from my local server or system  but it gives me error please help me
MY CODE:-

```
$inimage = new StdClass();
$image= file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); ;

$handle = fopen('$image', 'r');
$card_image = fread($handle, filesize($image));

fclose($handle);
$inimage->fileName = $image;    
$inimage->fileData = $card_image;
$params->OCRWSInputImage = $inimage;   

$settings = new StdClass();
$settings->ocrLanguages = array("ENGLISH");
$settings->outputDocumentFormat  = "TXT";
$settings->convertToBW = FALSE;
$settings->getOCRText = TRUE;
$settings->createOutputDocument = FALSE;
$settings->multiPageDoc = FALSE;
$settings->ocrWords = FALSE;
$params->OCRWSSetting = $settings;


try 
{
   $result = $client->OCRWebServiceRecognize($params);
} 
catch (SoapFault $fault) 
{
   print($client->__getLastRequest());
   print($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
}

var_dump($result);
print("Done");
?>
```

BUt IT gives following errors:-

> Notice: Undefined index: image in C:\xampp1\htdocs\google\g.php on line 18
>
> Warning: file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\xampp1\htdocs\google\g.php on line 18
>
> Warning: fopen($image): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp1\htdocs\google\g.php on line 22
>
> Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp1\htdocs\google\g.php on line 23
>
> Warning: fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp1\htdocs\google\g.php on line 25
> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["OCRWSResponse"]=> object(stdClass)#6 (3) { ["ocrText"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (0) { } ["errorMessage"]=> string(25) "Incorrect input file name" ["ocrWSWords"]=> object(stdClass)#8 (0) { } } } Don

Comment: You're actually reading the __content__ of the uploaded file to `$image` in `$image= file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);` and a line later you're treating `$image` as though it's a simple string containing the filename `$handle = fopen('$image', 'r');`

Comment: Please have a look on http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: In any case, `'$image'` is just that, a literal string containing a dollar symbol and the word 'image'. Remove the single quotes if you want this to be a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your HTML-Form-Data does not have a File named "image".

Additionally you are using file_get_contents in a wrong manner.

```
//This reads the file and put its contents into the $imagevariable
$image= file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']); ;
//Here you are trying to open a file with a name that was stored in your uploaded file.
$handle = fopen('$image', 'r');
$card_image = fread($handle, filesize($image));

fclose($handle);
```

I would suggest you to read the W3C tutorial on file_upload.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Sorry Sir, I have a ,html file like this:-                                                                          <form action="g.php" method="POST" 

enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="file" name="image" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>